# Server client with dynamic ip adress

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener, dynamic-ip

I have an a server application built in C# witch listens a tcp port an receive some data packages from clients. The problem is there are clients with dynamic ip address, so at a moment i have one client with more connections opened. I need a way to determine when the client changed his ip and close the old connection.

```
List<Socket> ClientsToRemove = new List<Socket>();

       ---this foreach this to avoid connections with the same ip address---                 
                   foreach(Socket client1 in AllConnections)
                    {
                        int count = 0;
                        foreach(Socket client2 in AllConnections)
                        {
                            if(((IPEndPoint)client1.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString() == ((IPEndPoint)client2.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString())
                            {
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
                        if(count>1)
                        {
                            AllConnections.Remove(client1);
                            UpdateActiveConnectionsBox(AllConnections.Count.ToString());
                        }
                    }

                   ---verify active connections---
                   foreach (Socket client in AllConnections)
                    {
                        if (!client.IsConnected())
                        {
                            ClientsToRemove.Add(client);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            UpdateLogBox("Active client IP:" + ((IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());
                        }    
                    }
                    UpdateLogBox("ACtive connection numer: " + AllConnections.Count.ToString());
                    foreach (Socket client in ClientsToRemove)
                        if (AllConnections.Contains(client))
                            AllConnections.Remove(client);

                    ClientsToRemove.Clear();
                    ClientsToRemove = null;

                    UpdateActiveConnectionsBox(AllConnections.Count.ToString());
                    Thread.Sleep(1500);
```

---

And this is where i accept new connections:

```
ServerMainSocket.Listen(10);
Socket TempSock = ServerMainSocket.Accept();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ClientFunction(TempSock); });

UpdateLogBox("New client connected from IP:" + ((IPEndPoint)TempSock.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());

if(AllConnections.Contains(TempSock) != true)
{ 
    AllConnections.Add(TempSock);
}
else
{
    AllConnections.Remove(TempSock);
    AllConnections.Add(TempSock);

    UpdateActiveConnectionsBox(AllConnections.Count.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Just your "verify" step should be sufficient to clean up old connections. (And, BTW, there's no need to "help" the GC by clearing your collection and setting your variable to `null`. It knows after `foreach (Socket client in ClientsToRemove)` has executed (assuming you remove the code I've said) that nothing else *reads* from the `ClientsToRemove` *variable* and therefore it's not a valid root to keep any object it's referencing alive)

Comment: and still i have 34 clients (i know for sure) and 41 connections with different ip opened :)

Comment: How long do your connections stay open for? Dynamic clients typically don't change their IP addresses frequently. In my experience on ADSL it was every couple of weeks, but on cable its virtually never. So are you sure it is because of clients changing their IP address? (And if a client does change its IP address then I would have expected that to break the connection.)

Comment: With dynamic IP addresses the IP addrress can get re-assigned to other PCs.  So there is no ways of just using the IP address (without PC name) that you are verifying that same client. You may be able to get host name (depending how dns is setup) using :                 IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAdress);

                machineName = hostEntry.HostName;

Comment: Yesterday I've added that "foreach to avoid connections with the same ip address". Before that, in 2 days of server running i have more than 3000 connections opened, ones with the same ip...So i don't understand either why the connections are not closing. I can tell than they are staying opened forever

Comment: Clients are some devices that use sim cards to send data packages

Comment: Are you controlling both ends of the communication and are you implementing your own protocol atop TCP? If so, add the client sending "heartbeat" messages every (5 minutes) say (if it's not sending anything else) and at the server end track each time anything arrives. Any socket that's not received anything for more than 7 minutes, then, say, should be closed as inactive.